Confused about change of non-standard vector basis
I was recently given a task of finding the transition matrix from basis B to S.
The bases are defined as follows:
$$
B = \left\{
\mathbf{b}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\ 
\mathbf{b}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix},\ 
\mathbf{b}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 8 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
$$
S = \left\{
\mathbf{s}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix},\ 
\mathbf{s}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 14 \\ 13 \end{bmatrix},\ 
\mathbf{s}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 9 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
Based on the formula from the Wikipedia article about change of basis:
$$ X_{old} = A * X_{new} $$
$A$ is the transition matrix between the bases, and can be found using the formula
$$ A = X_{new}^{-1} X_{old} $$
In this particular case:
$$ A = S^{-1} * B = \begin{bmatrix}
13 & 19 & \frac{181}{4} \\
-9 & -13 & -\frac{63}{2} \\
7 & 10 & \frac{99}{4}
\end{bmatrix}
 $$
But I was told that this is wrong and right answer looks like this:
$$ A = B^{-1} * S = \begin{bmatrix}
-27 & -71 & -41 \\
9 & 20 & 9 \\
4 & 12 & 8
\end{bmatrix}
 $$
I searched for examples and found conflicting information:

Here on StackExchange. Basically the same as my initial approach, matrix from $A$ to $B$ = $B^{-1} * A$
On Youtube. Matrix from $B$ to $B'$ = $B'^{-1} * B$. Same as I wanted to do initially.

I'm really confused about the correct approach to convert between bases. Why is my initial answer wrong, and what is the correct method for finding the transition matrix between two bases? Why it doesn't match with what other people do?

Your formula ($S^{-1} B$) is correct. $B^{-1} S$ would be the basis change matrix from $S$ to $B$.

First of all, what is $X_{new}^{-1}$? What is an inverse of a column? Also, there is no agreement on the definition of a transition matrix. What some call a transition matrix from $B$ to $S$, others call it a transition matrix from $S$ to $B$. Different books use different definitions. So you just have to choose one definition, and work with it. (but remember that some will use the other definition) The only difference is whether the formula will be $X_{new}=AX_{old}$ or $X_{old}=AX_{new}$. I'm used to the definition given in wikipedia.

@Mark
$X_{new}^{-1} = S^{-1} =
\left( \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 5 & 1 \
5 & 14 & 9 \
8 & 13 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \right)^{-1}
$
So the reason I'm getting confused is the difference between definitions?

@infernno Then I'm not entirely sure what you mean by $X_{new}$. In wikipedia (the link you posted), it is written that this is a column vector, the vector of coordinates. This is not a square matrix.

@Mark
Yeah, I see on Wikipedia that $X_{new}$ is column vector, but in my course material I saw that you can construct a square matrix by putting columns of given basis vectors, like I showed with $X_{new}^{-1} = S^{-1}$.
It does align with other examples I mentioned in my post

@infernno My definition of a transition matrix is the following: (like described in wikipedia) The $i$'th column is the column of coordinates of the $i$'th vector in the new basis with respect to the old basis. If the old basis is the standard basis then this is indeed like putting the vectors of the new basis as the columns of the matrix. But in your case, none of the bases is standard. And anyway, the formula $X_{old}=AX_{new}$ is irrelevant to this definition, this is something else. This formula is about how you can use the transition matrix.

This is how I studied it (to try not to think only in formulas)... When you want to change bases, you need to see how to write S in terms of B. So you try to write each vector s1, s2, s3, in terms of the three vectors from B
\begin{aligned}
    \alpha_1 \mathbf{b}_1 + \alpha_2 \mathbf{b}_2 + \alpha_3 \mathbf{b}_3 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        3 \\ 5 \\ 8
    \end{bmatrix}, \quad
    \beta_1 \mathbf{b}_1 + \beta_2 \mathbf{b}_2 + \beta_3 \mathbf{b}_3 =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        5 \\ 14 \\ 13
    \end{bmatrix}, \quad
    \lambda_1 \mathbf{b}_1 + \lambda_2 \mathbf{b}_2 + \lambda_3 \mathbf{b}_3 =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\ 9 \\ 2
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
And, replacing $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ by the respective vector, you end up with several equations to solve, which we can conveniently visualize like this:
\begin{aligned}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        2 & 3 & 8 \\
        1 & 3 & 2
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3
    \end{pmatrix}
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        3 \\ 5 \\ 8
    \end{pmatrix}, \quad
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        2 & 3 & 8 \\
        1 & 3 & 2
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \\ \beta_3
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        5 \\ 14 \\ 13
    \end{pmatrix}, \quad
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        2 & 3 & 8 \\
        1 & 3 & 2
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\ 9 \\ 2
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
And then with a little analysis, it's easy to see that we can build up a coefficient matrix:
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 14 & 9 \\
1 & 3 & 2 & 8 & 13 & 2 
\end{array}
(Applying Gaussian elimination) $\rightarrow$
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & -27 & -71 & -41 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 20 & 9 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 12 & 8 
\end{array}
This gives us the transition matrix between the bases, without the step of multiplying by the inverse

I assume that both basis are written in the same canonical basis $(e_i)_{i=1,2,3}$. Throughout this post, I'll use Einstein notation. So we get:
$$b_i=B_i^je_j \tag1$$
(this is the definition of the matrix $B$) and:
$$s_i=S_i^ke_k \tag2$$
(again, this is the definition of the matrix $S$). Now, if $A$ is the matrix representing the change-of-basis from $(b_i)_{i=1,2,3}$ to $(s_i)_{i=1,2,3}$, then:
$$s_i=A_i^jb_j \tag3$$
Plugging $(1)$ and $(2)$ into $(3)$ yields:
$$S_i^ke_k=A_i^jB_j^ke_k \tag4$$
and, by the linear independence of the basis vectors:
$$S_i^k=A_i^jB_j^k \tag5$$
Coherently with assuming the vectors as column-vectors, matrices' lower index is column's and the upper one is row's. But then $(5)$ must read as ($\vphantom{S}^t\_$ means "transpose"):
$$\vphantom{}^tS=\vphantom{}^tA\vphantom{}^tB=\vphantom{}^t(BA) \tag6$$
namely:
$$S=BA \tag7$$
whence:
$$A=B^{-1}S= \begin{pmatrix}
-27 & -71 & -41 \\
9 & 20 & 9 \\
4 & 12 & 8
\end{pmatrix}
\tag8$$
which matches with the one you was told.
